# controller is not geting view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
function export(){
$.ajax({ url: "@Url.Content("~/controllr/method")",
            type: 'GET',
            data: { selectedValue : $("#BranchId option:selected").text() },               
            traditional: true,
            async:false,
            success: function (result ) {
        },
        failure: function () {
            failed=true;
            alert("Error occured while processing your request");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {                
            failed=true;
            alert("Error occured while processing your request");
        }}
```

Comment: Don't you want a POST type?

Comment: By using post also I am not getting data.

Comment: Checking in the debug window (Ctrl-J in Chrome, and other browsers should have it), is there a value with $("#Branchld option:selected").text()? I would make sure that is providing data to be sent to the controller first. If you want help with that, then please post the HTML for that portion on your code.

Comment: yes, that branch id only I want to pass to controller. If I use alert for selected branch id, it shows correct branch id in above function.

Comment: how do you know that "controller is not geting view data"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a breakpoint on the controller action and see whether its is being hit ? Please try the following basic code and see whether the call is getting through

```
$.ajax({
    url: ‘@Url.Content(“~/MyController/MyMethod”)’,
    type: ‘post’,
    data: {
       selectedBranchId : $("#BranchId option:selected").text()
    }
});

// I am the controller action
public ActionResult MyMethod(string selectedBranchId)
{
    // your code
}
```

Please note I have dropped all the callback code and changed the controller name and the action name with the name of the postback variable